# Nullable DataTime/DateTimeOffset parameter in Header causing error in NSwag generated client

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, nswag

We have an Open Api specification that we are using to generate an Http client using the NSwag openapi2csclient from MSBuild.

```
<Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe) openapi2csclient /OperationGenerationMode:MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndPathSegments /UseBaseUrl:false /namespace:FooSpace /GenerateOptionalParameters:true /GenerateClientInterfaces:true /input:Clients/FooSpace/FooSpace-OpenApi.json /output:Clients/FooSpace/FooSpaceClient.cs" />
</Target>
```

It seems however that there is a problem when adding a non-required DateTime/DateTimeOffset as a parameter to a header for any method as this seems to be generated as a Nullable DateTime?/DateTimeOffset? in the Client-code.

The relevant parameter in the Open Api document:

```
{
    "name": "Updated",
    "in": "header",
    "schema": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time"
    }
}
```

The generated code-snippet that is failing:

```
if (updatedHeader != null)
    request_.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Updated", ConvertToString(updatedHeader.ToString("s"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

The above code snippets throws the error:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Query parameters with the same parameter are working fine as the Nullable's Value property is used instead in the generated code:

```
if (updatedQuery != null)
{
    urlBuilder_.Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString("Updated") + "=").Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString(updatedQuery.Value.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Append("&");
}
```

> Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was that the liquid template in the NSwag source code ([link](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/87d7ca7ba79d939ecc7977f36953249980e1f57a/src/NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp/Templates/Client.Class.HeaderParameter.liquid)) only adds a null-conditional operator when the parameter is set to Nullable as such:
`{% if parameter.IsNullable %}?{% endif %}`.

The problem is that when defining an optional parameter (as was the case for us) NSwag does not consider it nullable by default. Thus, we solved this by adding a line of code explicitly setting value type to Nullable like this:

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType == true) 
                    openApiParameter.Schema.Nullable = true;
```